# Printing every possible combination but must begin with 1-2 numbers and end with 10 characters of any kind

Tags: combinations

Is it possible to print every combination that begins with 1 or 2 numbers, then one - and in the end 10 letters from a-z, A-Z and 0-9.
Ex. 2-ErZI2eQSZ4
Ex. 16-teqOb7MU1g
The length of the combination would be from 12-13.
How long would it take and how big .txt would it be approximately?

Comment: Picking 10 characters from 62 possible characters is https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10+characters+from+62 . Multiply that by 100 to account for the leading numbers.

Comment: yeah you wont find a harddrive that fits.

Comment: Ok might find another project.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it statistically, there are two sets of combinations: the ones beginning with 1 number, and the ones beginning with 2 numbers. In the former case, there are 10 ways to pick the first number and 62 ways (26 lowercase letters + 26 uppercase letters + 10 digits = 62 characters) to pick each of the 10 characters. So this gives us 10 * 62 ^ 10 possible outcomes for the former case.
    The latter case has 10 ways to pick the first number, 10 ways to pick the second number, and 62 ways to pick each of the 10 other characters. So this gives us 10 * 10 * 62 ^ 10. Thus, the total number of combinations in the .txt file would have 10 * 62 ^ 10 + 10 * 10 * 62 ^ 10 lines. How long this would take depends on whether you are doing this by hand or by computer. It also depends on the language you are using if you plan to program this (which I sure would, if I had to generate all these combinations).

Comment: 26+26+10=62 so quite much more